import.meta.glob does not list freshly generated file
I have a function in an Astro file that generates an image, when it does not exist.
Then as a dynamic import I glob over the image dir and return the image.
const mapImg = ${currentDir}/../assets/${saveTo}/${imageFile};
... 
await map.image.save(mapImg, { compressionLevel: 9 }); 
const images = import.meta.glob<{ default: ImageMetadata }>( "/src/assets/*/map_.png", );
return await images[`/src/assets/${saveTo}/${imageFile}`](); 

So far the idea.
But glob does not list the freshly generated file. It is not in the images array.
I get this error:

images[saveTo2imageFile] is not a function

It might has something to do with static import of glob which is not able to reflect changes at runtime?
How can i dynamically import the generated image?

It might help to know that import.meta.glob is a thin wrapper around the corresponding vite function. Perhaps there is more docs about that.
